# Nextjs 13+ metadata and page data double fetching

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have simple next js app with app router NextJS13+. I'm using dynamic metadata exactly as in the doc.

```
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from 'next'

type Props = {
  params: { id: string }
 searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}

export async function generateMetadata(
 { params, searchParams }: Props,
 parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
 // read route params
 const id = params.id

 // fetch data
const product = await fetch(`https://.../${id}`).then((res) => res.json())

// optionally access and extend (rather than replace) parent metadata
const previousImages = (await parent).openGraph?.images || []

 return {
  title: product.title,
   openGraph: {
     images: ['/some-specific-page-image.jpg', ...previousImages],
  },
 }
}

export default function Page({ params, searchParams }: Props) {}
```

The problem I see is that on the same page I'm fetching from remote backend to get dynamic metadata I have to fetch same data to display on the page. In fact I have to call the api twice to first get metadata and second get data for the page. Is it normal, or I have missed something in the documentation ?

It seems logic there should be a way to share data you fetched from remote api to use for metadata and your page. Anyone idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NextJS automatically groups similar fetch requests and sends just one to the server.
As stated in their [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache)

> By default, data requests that use fetch are cached. You can use the cache and next.revalidate options of fetch to configure the caching behavior.

As well as [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns#fetching-data-where-its-needed) is stated:

> If you need to use the same data (e.g. current user) in multiple components in a tree, you do not have to fetch data globally, nor forward props between components. Instead, you can use fetch or React cache in the component that needs the data without worrying about the performance implications of making multiple requests for the same data. This is possible because fetch requests are automatically memoized

So yeah. Don't worry to have 2 separate `fetch` requests one in `Page` and one in `generateMetadata`.

Comment: is it only working when using fetch? or it works the same when using axios?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "",
};

export default async function page() {
  const data= await getPageData();
  metadata.title = data.title;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{metadata.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what your code snippet does to address the issue

Comment: The issue is in the open post - sharing data between the page metadata and the page itself.

It's a common task for SEO to put important keywords in the page's title tag and the h1 tag. 

In my code we get data only once in the default export of the Next page.tsx and then sharing it with the static metadata object. And we don't use the generateMetadata function whatsoever.

Comment: Please include details about this getPageData method...

Comment: getPageData  it's just an asynchronous function that you write. It could be anything, a fetch request to some API, an imported function from another file, a database query, etc. It's doesn't matter what's there.